# Why items method for dictionary is so much faster than a straightforward iteration?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, dictionary, hashtable

I'm practicing on LeetCode and came across [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-iii/) problem. I'm just learning algorithms and data structures in python, so don't know much about how some built-in methods are implemented and so my initial attempt was (python code)

```
return [num for num in Counter(nums) if Counter(nums)[num] == 1]
```

but it would take the entire 12.82 seconds to run on [this testcase](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/455388653/testcase/). On the other hand, there is a [very similar one liner](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-iii/discuss/931421/Python-One-Liner) in discussions

```
return [c[0] for c in Counter(nums).items() if c[1] == 1]
```

which utilizes the same idea but runs much faster, the aforementioned testcase took only 0.0022 seconds. Why is there such a difference in runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this code:

```py
return [num for num in Counter(nums) if Counter(nums)[num] == 1]
```

is that for each `num` in `Counter(nums)`, you have to create a new `Counter(nums)` to determine if the `if` condition is true or false. By using `Counter(nums).items()` in the second version:

```py
return [c[0] for c in Counter(nums).items() if c[1] == 1]
```

You have access to the number and its count already so there is no need to re-compute the count for each number.

Note I would write the comprehension as

```py
return [num for num, count in Counter(nums).items() if count == 1]
```

to make it a bit more obvious how it works.